# numpy on python 2.7 while having 3.6

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

So I scanned through the same question many times here however no one has given a straight answer.
I have started out with python 3.6 on Anaconda.. and I have numpy and all the  tools I need there. I am now faced with a project where I need to install python 2.7.
I need 2.7 to run a tool called pyfem - however pyfem relies on numpy which I only have on 3.6. Every time I run pip install it says I already have numpy on my 3.6 directory, even when I change directory on cmd : cd *2.7 directory* 
or even if I use cmd: pip install numpy *2.7 directory* 
it seems everytime I run pip it uses pip on 3.6 and it seems I have no 2.7 pip 
(pip or pip2 or pip-2.7) because I have no pip in 2.7 directory and every time I try to install it. I get a message on cmd pip 9.0.1 already exists in *3.6 directory*

Comment: Checkout `virtualenv` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and `virtualenvwrapper` (http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) <-- these are tools to help you create and manage "Virtual Environments", where you can have unique pip packages and unique versions of Python installed. You'll have to create 2 environments, 1 for your Py3.6 + NumPy, and another for your Py2.7 + NumPy. Check out this page for a whole walk through on using the above tools, creating virtualenvs and managing packages within them: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

You have `conda`, which provides you will tools for managing your Python version (which is what you need to be doing in this case). Go to the command line and create a new 2.7 environment, then activate:

```
conda create --name my_new_environment python=2.7 numpy
source activate my_new_environment
```

You will now be in a 2.7 environment with a 2.7-compat version of `numpy`. You can `pip install pyfem` from there and everything should be OK.

Comment: what if my 2.7 python is in a different directory ? I have my Anaconda in:
C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3 (which has 3.6)
while my 2.7 I installed not through anaconda and is in:
C:\Program Files\Python27

should I move my python ? or uninstall and reinstall inside anaconda ?

Comment: Where your Python is doesn't matter.

Comment: well I did something wrong now my anaconda won't run anymore neither will pip.
I'll just uninstall everything and get a new py2 and py3 and load them on eclipse and clear my head